# React update list on state change with hooks

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage, react-hooks

I am trying to make a photo album component in React which retrieves photo-urls from Firebase Storage and adds them to state with React Hooks. The problem is that the `<img/>` tags are never created, even though I can see that the image-urls are set correctly as state via the React Chrome Extension.

Complete code of the component:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {Fab} from "@material-ui/core";
import AddIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Add';
import {colorTheme} from "../constants/colors";
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import '@firebase/firestore';
import '@firebase/auth';
import '@firebase/storage';

export default function PhotoAlbum() {

    const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();

    const [images, setImages] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        loadImages();
    }, []);

    function loadImages() {
       let imageUrls = [];
        const imagesRef = storageRef.child('/images');
        imagesRef.listAll().then(res => {
            res.items.forEach(resItem => {
                resItem.getDownloadURL().then( url => {
                    imageUrls.push(url)
                })
            })
        }).then(() => setImages(imageUrls)); // I think this works, I can see the urls on the state
    }

    function handleChange(e) {
        let files = e.target.files;

        for(let i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
            const file = files[i];
            storageRef
                .child( `/images/${file.name}` )
                .put(file)
                .then( () => {
                    console.log( "Added file to storage! ", file.name );
                });
        }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {images.map((url, index) => (
                <img src={url} key={index.toString()} alt={'this is an image'}/> // These are never rendered
            ))}
            <div style={styles.floatingContainer}>
                <input
                    accept="image/*"
                    style={styles.input}
                    id="contained-button-file"
                    multiple
                    type="file"
                    onChange={handleChange}
                />
                <label htmlFor={"contained-button-file"}>
                <Fab
                    color='primary'
                    aria-label='add'
                    style={styles.floatingButton}
                    component="span">
                    <AddIcon/>
                </Fab>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

const styles = {
    floatingContainer: {
        borderRadius: '30px',
        position: 'absolute',
        right: '2vw',
        bottom: '2vh'
    },
    floatingButton: {
        backgroundColor: colorTheme.darkGreen,
    },
    input: {
        display: 'none',
    },
};
```

I am not that familiar with React and I am sure I have just misunderstood something. I apriciate any tips and help!

Comment: Mind dropping a `console.log(images);` or `debugger` in your function, right before the render would work, just to see what value the component is seeing/storing? Are there any errors occurring that aren't crashing your app?

Comment: Hey! So I tried adding a console.log like you suggested, like this: 
`return (
        <div>
            {console.log(images)}
            {images.map((url, index) => (
                <img src={url} key={index.toString()} alt={'this is an image'}/>
            ))}`
As (hopefully) expected it printed out first an empty array, and then an array of all my urls.

Comment: No, I meant inside the function before the return, but it seems it at least still printed the information needed. The next thing I would look at would be the rendered DOM in the browser's dev tools to ensure they `<img>` tags are making it there and you can inspect the CSS being applied. Is it possible to share a codesandbox that reproduces this issue?

Comment: I am not seeing any `<img/>` tags being added in the DOM when I inspect, that's kinda the issue. I will try to create a codesandbox.

Comment: I really tried to make a codesandbox, but I am having problems with setting up firebase correctly I think. I just get an `cross-origin error` and I'm suspecting it's from Firebase, so I tried setting up CORS open for all in Firebase and not requiering any authentication, but nothing works. Not sure how to get this up and running https://codesandbox.io/s/immutable-monad-yf6n5

Comment: I'm not familiar with setting up/configuring firebase, but was able to eliminate the `cross-origin` error by putting your `setInterval` call into a `setupFirebase` function and calling that in the onMount effect hook. I'm also able to run this exact code when I swap out all the firebase image retrieval code with an array of image ipsum image urls. After changing the inner check to `if (firebase.app)` and clearing the interval the code seems to fail on getting the storage ref.

Comment: I have the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually solved this, the problem was that I didn't update the state when the images were loaded, I just pushed them to an array, so the view never re-rendered. I changed it to this:

```
    function loadImages() {
            const imagesRef = storageRef.child('/images');
            imagesRef.listAll().then(res => {
                res.items.forEach(resItem => {
                    resItem.getDownloadURL().then(url => {
                        setImages(oldArray => [...oldArray, url]) // This line has changed!
                    })
                })
            });
        }
```

Now it works!